# Create dataframe column using another column for source variable suffix

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, where-clause

Difficult to title, so apologies for that...
Here is some example data:

```
region   FC_EA   FC_EM   FC_GL   FC_XX   FC_YY  ...
  GL       4       2       8       6       1    ...
  YY       9       7       2       1       3    ...
```

There are many columns with a suffix, hence the `...`

[edit] And there are many other columns. I want to keep all columns.

The aim is to create a column called `FC` that is the value according to the `region` column value.
So, for this data the resultant column would be:

```
FC
8
3
```

I have a couple of ways to achieve this at present - one way is minimal code (perhaps fine for a small dataset):

```
df['FC'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['FC_'+x.region], axis=1)
```

Another way is a stacked np.where query - faster for large datasets I am advised...:

```
df['FC'] = np.where(df.region=='EA', df.FC_EA,
             np.where(df.region=='EM', df.FC_EM,
             np.where(df.region=='GL', df.FC_GL, ...
```

I am wondering if anyone out there can suggest the best way to do this, if there is something better than these options?
That would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could use `melt`:

```
(df.melt(id_vars='region', value_name='FC')
   .loc[lambda d: d['region'].eq(d['variable'].str[3:]), ['region', 'FC']]
)
```

or using `apply` (probably quite slower):

```
df['FC'] = (df.set_index('region')
              .apply(lambda r: r.loc[f'FC_{r.name}'], axis=1)
              .values
            )
```

output:

```
  region  FC
4     GL   8
9     YY   3
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for response: I offered a `.apply()` solution above also myself! I don't think for my purposes the .melt() will suffice, as I need to keep all the columns on the dataframe... have updated original post to state this.